# Store the output of previous command issued by root user in a variable

Tags: shell, expect

I have a remote machine that I connect via **ssh** in an expect script. I run sequential commands or scripts on the remote machine and I need to know if they exit with an error or not.

**Problem:** I want to store exit status of previous process in a variable.

I know two things about the problem:

1. We can learn exit status of previous process by issuing `echo $?` command
2. I can retrieve the last send's output by using `$expect_out(buffer)`

here is the code:

```
spawn ssh $TARGET_USER@$TARGET_IP
expect "yes/no" {
    send "yes\r"
    expect "*?assword" { send "$TARGET_PASS\r"}
} "*?assword" { send "$TARGET_PASS\r"}

expect -re {\$ $}

# Delete start
send "su - root\r"
expect {
    "Password: " {send "$TARGET_PASS\r"}
}
# Delete end

send "sh /home/$TARGET_USER/xxx.sh\r"
expect -re {\$ $}

send "echo \$\?\r"; # '\r' used here to type 'return' .i.e new line
expect -re {\$ $}

set output $expect_out(buffer);
puts "------> $output <-------\n"

#logout from root
send "exit\r"
#logout from user
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

When I execute the above code, it's output:

```
------> su - root 
Password:  <-------
```

If I delete the piece of code that I mentioned in the above code (i.e no more 
 root), the output is like the following and it is exactly what I want:

```
------> echo $?
0 <-------
```

So, How can I achieve the output of last command issued by root via  `$expect_out(buffer)` in this particular case?

Comment: not sure if you have to use Expect. take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I would definitely love to check even if I have to use expect for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual:

> Upon matching a pattern (or `eof` or `full_buffer`), **any matching and previously unmatched output** is saved in the variable `expect_out(buffer)`.  Up to `9`  regexp substring  matches are saved in the variables `expect_out(1,string)` through `expect_out(9,string)`. `0` refers to strings which matched the entire pattern and is generated for glob patterns as well as regexp patterns.

So you can use `expect_out(N,string)` (0 ≤ N ≤ 9).

Example:

```
[STEP 101] # cat foo.exp
proc expect_prompt {} {
    upvar spawn_id spawn_id
    expect -re {bash-[.0-9]+[#$] $}
}

spawn bash --norc
expect_prompt

send "(exit 12)\r"
expect_prompt

send "echo \$?\r"
expect -re {[0-9]+}
set rcode $expect_out(0,string)
expect_prompt

send "echo 'Last command returned $rcode'\r"
expect_prompt

send "exit\r"
expect eof
[STEP 102] # expect foo.exp
spawn bash --norc
bash-4.4# (exit 12)
bash-4.4# echo $?
12
bash-4.4# echo 'Last command returned 12'
Last command returned 12
bash-4.4# exit
exit
[STEP 103] #
```

Comment: I could not find the connection between your answer and my problem. I think that my problem occurs because of changing user to root, **expect_out** returns me the output of previous user

Comment: expect knows nothing about you changing to another user. see the excerpt from expect manual regarding `expect_out(buffer)`.